# Firefox headless mode with Selenium: why does it remember old access?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to make up a system in order to automate sign-in procedure on booking.com.

What I want to accomplish is that when I visit the following page: https://join.booking.com/?lang=it , the browser have to show me the sign-in form as I was visiting it for the first time.

Unfortunately it doesn't happen, somehow Firefox remembers that I have already done something on this page and show me the "continue to register" page. I read that selenium always has a fresh start, I have disabled cache memory, form auto-fill but still I can't get it done.

Any suggestions? Maybe some Firefox preference should be set, like cache memory ecc...

Working with python 2.7.9, selenium 3.141.0 and geckodriver 0.26.0

```
import time
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

def initialize_driver():

    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    options.add_argument("--private")
    print(options)

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Users/giovanni/Documents/IA_beta_v0.0.0/tools/geckodriver', options=options)
    try:
        driver.get("https://www.google.com")
        print("Driver successfully initialized\n")
    except:
        print("Error while initializing driver\n")

    return driver

def close_driver(driver):

    try:
        driver.close()
        print("Driver closed correclty\n")
    except:
        print("An error occured when trying to shut down driver\n")

def new_registration():

    print("Enter name: ")
    name = raw_input()
    print("Enter surname: ")
    surname = raw_input()
    print("Enter email: ")
    email_address = raw_input()

    print("\nPlease check the information you have entered:\n")
    print("Name = %s;\n" %name)
    print("Surname = %s;\n" %surname)
    print("Email address = %s;\n" %email_address)

    print("Are these information correct?(y/n)\n")
    user_answer = raw_input()

    if user_answer == 'y':
        print("Proceeding with entablishing connection with Booking.com\n")
    elif user_answer == 'n':
        print("What information would you like to change?\n")
        print("\t-name;\n")
        print("\t-surname;\n")
        print("\t-email;\n")

        user_answer = raw_input()

        if user_answer == 'name':
            print("You have choose to modify the name for the registration\n")
            name = substitute_info_registration(1,name)
            print("\nNew name is %s\n" %name)
        elif user_answer == 'surname':
            print("You have choose to modify the surname for the registration\n")
            surname = substitute_info_registration(2,surname)
            print("\nNew name is %s\n" %surname)
        elif user_answer == 'email':
            print("You have choose to modify the email address for the registration\n")
            email_address = substitute_info_registration(3,email_address)
            print("\nNew name is %s\n" %email_address)
        else:
            print("Wrong input. Please enter one of the three options\n")
    else:
        print("Wrong input. Please enter one of the two options\n")

    booking_registration_procedure(name,surname,email_address)

def substitute_info_registration(flag,info):

    if flag == 1:
        print("Current name is %s. Which is going to be the new name? " %info)
        user_answer = raw_input()
        print("New name is %s.\n" %user_answer)
    elif flag == 2:
        print("Current surname is %s. Which is going to be the new surname? " %info)
        user_answer = raw_input()
        print("New surname is %s.\n" %user_answer)
    elif flag == 3:
        print("Current email address is %s. Which is going to be the new email address? " %info)
        user_answer = raw_input()
        print("New email address is %s.\n" %user_answer)

        return user_answer

def booking_registration_procedure(name,surname,email_address):

    print("Initializing driver...\n")
    firefox = initialize_driver()

    #STEP 1

    firefox.get('https://join.booking.com/?lang=it')
    #source = firefox.page_source

    try:
        firefox.save_screenshot('/Users/giovanni/Documents/IA_beta_v0.0.0/screenshot/first_page.jpg')
        print("Screenshot taken correctly\n")
    except:
        print("Can't take first screenshot\n")

    try:
        name_surname_form = firefox.find_element_by_id('ultranet_label_input_0')
        name_surname_form.send_keys(name + " " + surname)
        email_address_form = firefox.find_element_by_id('ultranet_label_input_1')
        email_address_form.send_keys(email_address)
        firefox.save_screenshot('/Users/giovanni/Documents/IA_beta_v0.0.0/screenshot/first_page_after_filling_form.jpg')
    except:
        print("Can't fill form with name, surname and email address\n")
        close_driver(firefox)
        exit(1)

    try:
        continue_button = firefox.find_elements_by_name('save')
        print continue_button
        continue_button[0].click()
        time.sleep(2)
        firefox.save_screenshot('/Users/giovanni/Documents/IA_beta_v0.0.0/screenshot/first_page_after_clicking_button.jpg')
    except:
        print("Can't click continue button\n")

    close_driver(firefox)
```

Comment: Selenium should have a "fresh start". Can you post your code?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @0m3r code added.